# No Method Error in Japas#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I generated a scaffold called `rounds`. Here is what my `JapasController` looks like:

```
class JapasController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_japa, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
  def index
    @japas = Japa.all
    @users = User.all
  end
  def show
  end
  def new
    @japa = current_user.japas.build
  end
  def edit
  end
  def create
    @japa = current_user.japas.build(japa_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @japa.save
        format.html { redirect_to @japa, notice: 'Japa was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @japa }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @japa.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @japa.update(japa_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @japa, notice: 'Japa was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @japa }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @japa.errors, status:     :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
  def destroy
    @japa.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to japas_url, notice: 'Japa was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_japa
    @japa = Japa.find(params[:id])
  end
  def correct_user
    @japa = current_user.japas.find_by(id: params[:id])
    redirect_to japas_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this japacount" if @japa.nil?
  end
  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def japa_params
    params.require(:japa).permit(:rounds, :comment, :user_id)
  end
end
```

Japa Model:

```
 class Japa < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
 end
```

User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
       :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
   has_many :japas
end
```

Here is my index template for `Japas`:

```
      <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
   <center>
   <h1>Listing Japa</h1>

  <table class = 'table table-hover' style = 'width:700px;'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Rounds</th>
        <th>Goal</th>


        <th colspan="3"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <% @users.each do |user| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= user.japas.created_at %></td>
          <td><%= user.japas.rounds %></td>
          <td> / 16 </td>

          <td><%= link_to 'Show', japa %></td>
          <% if japa.user == current_user %>
          <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_japa_path(japa) %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', japa, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
          <%end%>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Total Sum</td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
     </tbody>
     </table>
    </center>

  <br>
  <% if user_signed_in? %>
   <%= link_to 'New Japa', new_japa_path %>
   <%end%>
```

Here is my error message when I load: `http://localhost:3000/japas`.

```
NoMethodError in Japas#index

Showing /Users/vvd/Desktop/japacounter/app/views/japas/index.html.erb where line #20 raised:

undefined method `created_at' for #<User:0x007f981a4536e8>
Extracted source (around line #20):

<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= user.japas.created_at %></td>
    <td><%= user.japas.rounds %></td>
    <td> / 16 </td>
```

This is a picture of the error page I am receiving:
[image: Screenshot of Error page]

Comment: @user4703663 ok I entered rails console and typed Japa.attributes and received a no method error on attributes.

Comment: Please show your `Japa` and `User` model

Comment: Please post the complete error: `undefined method created_at  ..... ?`. What's the relationship between user and japas?

Comment: @Prashant4020  I have edited my description of the error with Japa and User Model.

Comment: @NitishParkar I have taken a screenshot of the complete error and put it as an update in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your requirements on comments you can try this on.

You have to change your controller action as following for getting `japas` for the `current_user`

```
def index
    @japas = Japa.where(user_id: current_user.id) 
end
```

And in view iterate with @japas, as following

```
  <% @japas.each do |japa| %>   
     <tr>
      <td><%= japa.created_at %></td>
      <td><%= japa.rounds %></td>
     </tr>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not call an attribute/method like `created_at` with an active record associations collection. `User` has many `Japa`, so you can re-write you view as following in error area with rest of your code. Just iterate within `user.japas`.

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
   <% user.japas.each do |japa| %>   
  <tr>
     <td><%= japa.created_at %></td>
     <td><%= japa.rounds %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: ok, I've implemented it on my site and kept the created_at. Everything worked. The error message is gone, but the function that I wanted is not there. I want only the Japas that are created by the user who created it to be seen only by him.

Comment: I have added another answer based on your requirements.